# Create a specific form in Drupal

Tags: forms, drupal

I need to build a form where user can have an infinite number of identical fields, depending on the number which he entered in the previous field 'Number of steps'(for example).
Maybe someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you to check the Form API of Drupal and especially the [#ajax property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax)

[Here is a great example](https://www.drupal.org/node/752056) on how to achieve what you need.